# How to find rows that contain string in plsql function

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

When i try to implement the function to find if rows contain a string.
The function always return 0.

This is my function

```
member function  containsText (pString1 varchar2, pString2 varchar2)return integer is
checked integer;
begin
if INSTR(pString2,pString1)=0 then checked := 0;
else checked := 1 ;
end if;
return checked;
end containsText;
```

1. i implement the function like below,

> containsText (table_name.column_name, 'some_string_here');

it returns 0.

2 i try to find out why it doesn't work by using the code below,

> containsText('abcdefg','fg');

it returns 0 as well.

3. i try instr method alone, it works

> instr('abcdefg','fg');

it returns 6.

4. i use instr in query to implement my original idea

> select instr(table_name.column_name,'Great') from table_name

it works. How could i make this function working as my expect?

Comment: Are you trying to write a global PL/SQL function or to create an object type that has a member function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
member function  containsText (pString1 varchar2, pString2 varchar2)return integer is
checked integer;
begin
if INSTR(pString1, pString2)=0 then checked := 0;
else checked := 1 ;
end if;
return checked;
end containsText;
```

You change in INSTR(pString1, pString2)=0

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments to `INSTR` reversed. Also you have a `MEMBER` function but do not appear to be using any features that would require this. You could use:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TYPE test_obj AS OBJECT(
  value VARCHAR2(20),
  MEMBER FUNCTION checkText(
    self  IN OUT test_obj,
    match IN     VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE BODY test_obj IS 
  MEMBER FUNCTION checkText(
    self  IN OUT test_obj,
    match IN     VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN LEAST( INSTR( self.value, match ), 1 );
  END;
END;
/
```

**Testing**:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_test test_obj := test_obj( 'abcdefgh' );
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_test.checkText( 'gh' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_test.checkText( 'i' ) );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1
> 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e815d65e63e9ee49d920dc6112804e1)*

---

You could also write it without the `SELF` argument and taking two strings (as you've done in the question) but there does not seem to be much point of making this a `MEMBER` function of a type and it could just be a global stored-function or a `STATIC` function of the type.

```sql
CREATE TYPE test_obj AS OBJECT(
  unused_value VARCHAR2(20),
  MEMBER FUNCTION checkText( -- could be STATIC FUNCTION
    value IN     VARCHAR2,
    match IN     VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE BODY test_obj IS 
  MEMBER FUNCTION checkText( -- could be STATIC FUNCTION
    value IN     VARCHAR2,
    match IN     VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    IF INSTR( value, match ) = 0 THEN
      RETURN 0;
    ELSE
      RETURN 1;
    END IF;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_test test_obj := test_obj( 'xyz' );
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_test.checkText( 'abcdefgh', 'gh' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_test.checkText( 'abcdefgh', 'x' ) );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1
> 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3a32ed7f2bba1125d6eb63909890e675)*